# Polymorphism concept in objective c?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, uiviewcontroller

**I have changed my question Now...**

I want to know how to do `polymorphism` in `objective c`  like

```
Animal = new Dog();

Animal = new Cat();
```

Now i like to do it like

```
UIViewController *controller = [CheckController alloc]initWithNibName:@"CheckController" bundle:nil];
```

I want to create a method and pass my `xib file` name and `controllerName` like this..

```
-(void)openNewViewController:(UIViewController *)controllerObject: (NString)*nibName 
{
    // overhere it should do it something like given

     UIViewController *object =[controllerObject alloc]initWithNibName:nibName bundle:nil];

     [self.navigationController pushViewController:object  animated:YES];

}
```

but don't know how to do this...

share some code please ...

In simple words i want to open a new view **on click of a Button**. And I want to create a **function** inside it where I pass `controllerName` and `Nib file` and it will open the View for me..

Thanks in Advance...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subclass `UIButton`.
Add property `NSString* nibName` in it.
Set this property for all yours buttons.

In tap handler:

```
- (IBAction) onBtn:(MyButton*)sender {
    UIViewController* vc = [[NSClassFromString(sender.nibName) alloc] initWithNibName:sender.nibName bundle:nil];
    [self.navigationController pushViewController:vc animated:YES];// or other code with viewcontroller
    //add [vc release]; if it's not ARC
}
```

Comment: I don't know how to Subclass UIButton